# instanceof returns false on a true condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord.js

**CONTEXT**

```js
// discord-debug
import { Client } from 'discord.js';

export class Debugger {
    constructor(public client: Client) {
        console.log(client instanceof Client); // logs false
    }
}

// main.ts
import { Client } from 'discord.js';
import { Debugger } from 'discord-debug';

const client = new Client({ intents: [...] }); // intents can be anything

console.log(client instanceof Client) // logs true

const debug = new Debugger(client);
```

if I move **discord-debug** into the root folder of "`main.ts`", it logs true

I'm publishing my **npm package**, [discord-debug](https://npmjs.com/package/discord-debug), and while testing it locally, it works well. But when I install it via `npm` or an external folder, it throws the following error:

```js
throw new TypeError('`client` must be a discord.js Client instance');
            ^

TypeError: `client` must be a discord.js Client instance
```

Which is defined in [this line](https://github.com/Dqrshan/discord-debug/blob/master/src/index.ts#L53C9-L53C9)

Since the error doesn't cover much of the issue, it really is a hard task figuring it out and fixing it.

**UPDATE**

```json
// package.json in "discord-debug"
"peerDependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^14.11.0"
},
```

And when I use the package, I get the following error:

```js
node_modules/discord-debug/dist/index.d.ts:1:49 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'discord.js' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { Client, Message, type Snowflake } from 'discord.js';
                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/discord-debug/dist/lib/Command.d.ts:1:87 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'discord.js' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { ChatInputCommandInteraction, Collection, Message, SlashCommandBuilder } from 'discord.js';
```

**NOTES**

- When I use `console.log(client)` in **discord-debug**, it logs "undefined"
- The version of `peerDependency` discord.js of **discord-debug** is the same as the `dependency` discord.js of the project being worked on

**FILE STRUCTURE**

```
discord-debug/
├── dist/
│   ├── commands/
│   ├── lib/
│   └── index.js
├── src/
│   ├── commands/
│   ├── lib/
│   └── index.ts
└── tests/
    └── main.js
my-project/
└── src/
    └── main.ts
```

- requiring `discord-debug` via `../dist` in `tests/main.js` works.
- requiring `discord-debug` in **my-project** via `npm i ../discord-debug` throws the error.

Comment: What does "*folder/outside/root*" mean? Does that folder have its own packages, its own *node_modules*, its own version of the *discord.js* library?

Comment: "folder/outside/root" is the *local* version of the package being installed, and yes it has its own node_modules which is the same version of the discord.js library as the root. Also, if I delete node_modules (in the package folder), i get the module not found error

Comment: Then that's the problem - it has its own copy with its own class, which is named the same but is still distinct. Can you add more details about your file hierarchy and desired module structure to the question please? Are you working on a library or on an application?

Comment: sure! I have added the file structure and more details.
I'm working on an application (a tool would be a better way to describe it)

Comment: Oh I missed you already wrote "*I'm publishing my npm package, discord-debug*". Then it shouldn't matter where the source code of that library is located if you install it from npm. Regarding "*when I install it via npm*", how exactly did you do that? Are both *discord.js* and *discord-debug* in the *package.json* of *my-project*? Where is the *node_modules* folder of *my-project* located?

Comment: for testing the package locally, I use `npm i ../discord-debug` in another project. And yes, both `discord-debug` and `discord.js` are in the package.json of **my-project**.

Revisiting, if I create `tests/main.js` in *discord-debug* folder, I can import `Debugger` via `import { Debugger } from '../dist'` and it works as expected. Whereas, if I use it in *my-project* via `import { Debugger } from 'discord-debug'`, it throws an error...`Cannot find module 'discord.js' or its corresponding type declarations`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254251/discussion-between-darshan-b-and-bergi).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the two directories have separate `node_modules` folders, it's correct that `instanceof` returns `false`, because `instanceof` checks that the class is somewhere in the instance's prototype chain via reference equality. You'll hit similar issues with real-world usage of your library if the consuming code happens to use a different version of the `discord` library. For that reason, it's typically better for library code to use duck typing for any necessary type checks that rely on external dependencies (or simply rely on TypeScript + documentation and don't check at runtime at all).

Comment: It is also a typical use case for `peerDependencies` instead of `dependencies`.

Comment: I used `peerDependencies` for `discord.js` v14, and now the package throws "Cannot find module 'discord.js' or its corresponding type declarations"